# Calling postValue() multiple times on a Livedata will result only the last one is dispatched. Is there any alternative solution for that?

Tags: android, android-livedata

[As the document says about the Livedata#postValue(T)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#postValue(T)):

> If you called this method multiple times before a main thread executed
> a posted task, only the last value would be dispatched.

But I really need to call postValue() multiple times on a Livedata in a short time. I am designing a application with downloading function. I write the downloading code inside an AndroidViewmodel, and start a new Thread for each asyns downloading task. As soon as each task is completed, it postValue() to a Livedata, so there may be many tasks posting value to the same Livedata at the same time, which resulted that only the last posting works.

Is there anyway to enable me to postValue() multiple times to a Livedata at the same time and ensure all of the relative Observer react to all the posting?

------My code example is as below---------------

In the AndroidViewModel class:

```
private MutableLiveData<DataHolder_Task> completedTask;
    ......
        public void bulkDownload(List<DataHolder_Task> tasks){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(DataHolder_Task task:tasks)
                   {
                      //download() blocks untill task completed
                        download(task); 
                        completedTask.postValue(task);
                   }
                }
            }).start();
        }

public MutableLiveData<DataHolder_Task> getCompletedTask() {
    if(completedTask==null){
        completedTask=new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return completedTask;
}
```

In an Activity:

```
    androidViewModel.bulkDownload(a_list_of_tasks)
    androidViewModel.getCompletedTask().observe(this, new Observer<DataHolder_Task>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(DataHolder_Task task) {
            doSomething(task)
        }
    });
```

Comment: In short: no, this is not possible. What you should do instead, is change what you expose with your LiveData. Your LiveData should hold the collection of each result and the ViewModel is responsible for merging the results in a single class. For instance, if you have `LiveData<Drawable>` now, you could expose a `LiveData<List<Drawable>>`. If you'd like a more specific answer, you could share a snippet of your code to get kickstarted

Comment: @Michiel Hi, thanks for the comment. I have updated my code example. Actually I have ever considered exposing LiveData<List<T>>, but if I use this solution, I have to update all the data in one shot, while I expect update them real-time. For example, if I am downloading 100 images, I would like to display them one by one, instead of, taking  very long time to wait for all of their completing.

Comment: It has been years since I've used `Thread`s directly, so bare some rookie mistakes. If you have the time and it's worth the effort, I'd suggest to look into Kotlin and coroutines / Flow.

Comment: By looping over tasks inside a single Runnable, does't that result in downloading the task one by one? If you instead create a Runnable per task, the complete download will finish quicker. This is because there is no dead time between server and client; it will occur less that server ánd client are waiting

Comment: Also when exposing `LiveData<List<T>>`, you can show intermediate progress. If at first you wanted to expose T(1), then T(2), then T(3), now you can expose: [T(1)], then [T(1), T(2)] and then [T(1), T(2), T(3)]. This needs some extra precautions and logic: due to race conditions the order of the list is not granted, if this is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this by subclass `MutableLiveData`, add a queue to buffer the bulk live datas, then dispatch one by one to the main thread:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import java.util.*

class QueuedMutableLiveData<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    private val queue = LinkedList<T?>()

    override fun setValue(value: T) {
        super.setValue(value)
        synchronized(queue) {
            queue.pollFirst()
            queue.peekFirst()?.run {
                super.postValue(this)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun postValue(value: T?) {
        synchronized(queue) {
            queue.add(value)
            if (queue.size == 1) {
                super.postValue(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we use ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `.setValue()` (or `.value` for Kotlin) instead of `.postValue()`. Works for me.

Comment: True `.setValue()` works just fine

Answer (score 1):

LiveData is designed as a life-cycle aware observable object that informs a UI of the *latest* state. It is not an event stream.

> Is there any alternative solution for that?

Try a [Kotlin Flow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow).

Comment: Thanks. Kotlin Flow can resolve this problem.